# React rendering everytime state changes

Tags: reactjs, components, render, lifecycle

That is the way react works right?, is it bad on large scale application?
When would I want it not to render on every state change, and how is it done?

(Using function components)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to handle your state is by using a State container like Redux or useContext from react
you can find more informations here :
React-redux : https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started
UseContext : https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_usecontext.asp